# LoadLibrary python with dll write in c++

Tags: python, c++, dll

I have write a python script that load a dll writed in c++ .

Script is :

```
from ctypes import *
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary('C:\\Users\\gpiscite\\Documents\\Project\\DllXPython\\Debug\\DllXPython.dll')
mydll
mydll.fnDllXPython(956, c_char_p("c_char_p"), c_void_p(0), "std::string")
```

The c++ code is compiled in VisualStudio as a DLL and it is:

```
// DllXPython.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "DllXPython.h"


// This is an example of an exported variable
DLLXPYTHON_API int nDllXPython=0;

// This is an example of an exported function.
DLLXPYTHON_API int fnDllXPython(int aInt, char* apChar, void* apVoid, std::string aString)
//DLLXPYTHON_API PyObject * fnDllXPython(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{

    return 0;

}
```

I had attached debug on python process and i saw thad the exception was raised on return 0 execution . The exception raised is:

Debug Assertion Failed! ..... _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) ....

Any idea ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"std::string" is not a std::string. It is merely a char*

Comment: wath is the equivalent of std::string in python?

Comment: Don't think there is one for ctypes. I don't know personally but check out SWIG to see if can deal with this.